# Pause/Resume functions for timer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to use a timer which can be paused and resumed. As far as I know there is only one timer in Python which is contained in the `threading` package, but I cannot pause or resume it, only cancel it.

This is a standard code to use the timer in Python:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def timeout():
     print "Game over"

t = Timer(20 * 60, timeout)
t.start()
```

So what should I do to realize pause/resume functions with this timer?

Answer (score 5):

```
import threading, time

class ResumableTimer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.callback = callback
        self.timer = threading.Timer(timeout, callback)
        self.startTime = time.time()

    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def pause(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.pauseTime = time.time()

    def resume(self):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(
            self.timeout - (self.pauseTime - self.startTime),
            self.callback)

        self.timer.start()
```

Your homework:

- Inheritance?
- Exceptions? Checks?
- Something better than a resumable timer

Comment: Try it, `t = ResumableTimer(5, someFunction); t.start(); t.pause(); t.resume()` and mark my question as correct if it works.

Comment: Better add `max(0, ...)` as timers can be a few nanoseconds late and if you call `pause()` just during this time you will get a negative value in `resume()` that may upset the `Timer()` initialisation, e.g. throwing an exception "cannot travel back in time".

Answer (score 1):

final class release

```py
from threading import Timer
import time


class RenewableTimer:

    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.timer = Timer(timeout, callback)

        self.start_time = None
        self.cancel_time = None

        # Used for creating a new timer upon renewal
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.callback = callback

    def cancel(self):
        self.timer.cancel()

    def start(self):
        # NOTE: erroneously calling this after pausing causes errors where
        # start_time is updated, and then you get a RuntimeError
        # for trying to restart a thread
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.timer.start()

    def pause(self):
        self.cancel_time = time.time()
        self.timer.cancel()
        return self.get_remaining_time()

    def resume(self):
        self.timeout = self.get_remaining_time()
        self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.callback)
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.timer.start()

    def get_remaining_time(self):
        if self.start_time is None or self.cancel_time is None:
            return self.timeout
        return self.timeout - (self.cancel_time - self.start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider is to keep track of the time that passes during each period you would "stop" the timer, but actually leave the timer running. Then at the end of the task, just subtract the total paused time from the total elapsed time.

```
import keyboard
from timeit import default_timer as timer

elapsedPauseTime = 0;

print("'s' to start task timer")
print("'p' to pause task timer")
print("'r' to resume task timer")
print("'e' to end task timer")

while (1 == 1):
    if keyboard.read_key() == "s":
        print("Task Timer Started")
        timerStart = timer()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("Task Timer pause counter started")
        timerPauseStart = timer()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "r":
        print("Task Timer pause counter stopped")
        timerPauseEnd = timer()
        elapsedPauseTime = elapsedPauseTime + timerPauseEnd - timerPauseStart
    if keyboard.read_key() == "e":
        print("Task Timer Ended")
        timerEnd = timer()
        break

print("Total time: " + str(timerEnd - timerStart))
print("Pause time: " + str(elapsedPauseTime))
print("Task time with pauses: " + str(timerEnd - timerStart - elapsedPauseTime))
```