# How to make a pausable timer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I want to create a timer in python with the following functions:

`timer.start()` - should start the timer

`timer.pause()` - should pause the timer

`timer.resume()` - should resume the timer

`timer.get()` - should return the current time

The timer should run from 0 upwards. It is meant to measure time, not trigger a callback function.

So if you start it, it should start counting the seconds like 0 1 2 3, if you pause it, it should be stilll at 3, but not going further. After its resumed it then goes on with 4 5 6 and so on

How can I do this?

---

[Pause/Resume functions for timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089391/pause-resume-functions-for-timer) is not a duplicate because I do not care about callbacks.

Comment: Your question talks about timers. I do not get what the difference between what you need and the linked post should be.Maybe [edit] your question and add relevant information?

Comment: I edited it, but since it is closed i will have to make a new one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027221/how-to-make-a-pausable-time-measure-timer

Comment: Please don’t duplicate your question. If the edit is sufficient, your question will be reopened.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want the timer to actually *count* (e.g. constantly print to the screen) or just provide the time on ˋtimer.get()ˋ? Do you just want second precision (as counting implies) or the precision of the computer‘s clock?

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework prompt

Comment: "Pause/Resume functions for timer is not a duplicate because I do not care about callbacks." So why not just... take out the part of the code that handles callbacks? Or pass a callback that doesn't do anything? Or look at other answers that don't involve callbacks (since the question there didn't ask for them)?

Comment: I'd think the question is whether there is a built-in for this or some popular or well-maintained module. This is easy to implement and sure there is code on the net that one could copy but we don't want to unnecessarily bloat our code with our own implementation of utility functions or with code copied from other projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# mytimer.py
from datetime import datetime
import time

class MyTimer():
    """
    timer.start() - should start the timer
    timer.pause() - should pause the timer
    timer.resume() - should resume the timer
    timer.get() - should return the current time
    """

    def __init__(self):
        print('Initializing timer')
        self.timestarted = None
        self.timepaused = None
        self.paused = False

    def start(self):
        """ Starts an internal timer by recording the current time """
        print("Starting timer")
        self.timestarted = datetime.now()

    def pause(self):
        """ Pauses the timer """
        if self.timestarted is None:
            raise ValueError("Timer not started")
        if self.paused:
            raise ValueError("Timer is already paused")
        print('Pausing timer')
        self.timepaused = datetime.now()
        self.paused = True

    def resume(self):
        """ Resumes the timer by adding the pause time to the start time """
        if self.timestarted is None:
            raise ValueError("Timer not started")
        if not self.paused:
            raise ValueError("Timer is not paused")
        print('Resuming timer')
        pausetime = datetime.now() - self.timepaused
        self.timestarted = self.timestarted + pausetime
        self.paused = False

    def get(self):
        """ Returns a timedelta object showing the amount of time
            elapsed since the start time, less any pauses """
        print('Get timer value')
        if self.timestarted is None:
            raise ValueError("Timer not started")
        if self.paused:
            return self.timepaused - self.timestarted
        else:
            return datetime.now() - self.timestarted

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = MyTimer()
    t.start()
    print('Waiting 2 seconds'); time.sleep(2)
    print(t.get())
    print('Waiting 1 second'); time.sleep(1)
    t.pause()
    print('Waiting 2 seconds [paused]'); time.sleep(2)
    print(t.get())
    print('Waiting 1 second [paused]'); time.sleep(1)
    print(t.get())
    print('Waiting 1 second [paused]'); time.sleep(1)
    t.resume()
    print('Waiting 1 second'); time.sleep(1)
    print(t.get())
```

Run

```
python mytimer.py
```

Output

```
Initializing timer
Starting timer
Waiting 2 seconds
Get timer value
0:00:02.001523
Waiting 1 second
Pausing timer
Waiting 2 seconds [paused]
Get timer value
0:00:03.004724
Waiting 1 second [paused]
Get timer value
0:00:03.004724
Waiting 1 second [paused]
Resuming timer
Waiting 1 second
Get timer value
0:00:04.008578
```

Comment: I modified the code slightly using module `keyboard` running in a loop expecting keyboard inputs 's' -> t.Start(), 'p'->t.Pause(), 'r'->t.Resume(). After Start() -> Pause() -> Resume() I get result like `-1 day, 22:30:39.113534`. Any ideas?

Comment: @zooid open a new question, post your code and post the new question link here.

Comment: No, thanks. I'll pass. Not going through that experience again on this website. First the site needs to change the policy and practice of bashing new questions.

Comment: I'll help you and answer it but it needs to be a new question since this one already has an accepted answer.

Comment: I don't quite get why don't you just make an update of your answer. The mere fact that I get this kind of result means your answer has been incomplete. Just update it and add the "CAVEAT: due to this and that you may get this wrong result, here's the solution." Anyways, it's your preference if you wanna help the people or not. I already moved on to C# because your solution didn't work.

Comment: "I modified the code slightly" / "I get result like -1 day, 22:30:39.113534" - Difficult for me to figure out what modifications you made and what issue you're seeing. I suggested opening a new question because (1) you can post the code properly formatted, (2) I can answer with a properly formatted response, and (3) the status of your question can be properly tracked. If you're not willing to do that, fine, just give me more details so I can help.

Comment: you can find the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124888/using-datetime-module-to-create-pause-able-timer-getting-weird-results

Comment: Thanks for posting it as a new question so that I could understand your issue better and help you out. TL;DR the keyboard loop was calling `resume` repeatedly on each keypress, and the pause check was disabled so the `resume` method was subtracting the pause time several times resulting in a negative state.