# How to make countdown timer in python with ability to pause and resume?

Tags: python

I'm new at python.
I want to make event based countdown program in python (without any external library) that has pause resume functionality and abort functionality. We could add event to pause function and when pause runs it should run its particular function which is assigned with event.

```
import time
class countdown:
    def __init__(self,Time,fun):
        self.time=Time
        self.fun=fun
        self.paused=False
        self.aborted=False
    def run(self,*funs):
        # how can i modify this code to add pause, resume,  abort functionality 
        # with event system so I can add function like on and then event
        # "pause" or "resume" and pass function to it so when countdown
        # pause or resume then it will pause and execute that function please help
        while self.time>0:
            print(self.time)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.time-=1
        self.fun(*funs)
    def pause(self):
        # code to pause countdown
    def resume(self):
        # code to resume countdown
    def abort(self):
        # code to abort countdown
def samplefun(Yname,Yage):# this is the function to run when countdown finish.
    print('hi {a} you are {b} years old.'.format(a=Yname,b=Yage))
count=countdown(10,samplefun)
count.run('John Doe','30')
time.sleep(3)
count.pause()   # how can I make up code so when I use pause function it should pause the countdown in 7 but it doesnot pause at 7 instead of that it run 
                #pause function after countdown completes
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a pausable timer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60026296/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite strategy for this task is to create a periodic task object using the threading library. Here is an example

```
class Periodic(object):
"""
A periodic task running in threading.Timers
"""

    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._timer = None
        self.function = function
        self.interval = interval
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self._stopped = True
        if kwargs.pop('autostart', True):
            self.start()

    def start(self, from_run=False):
        self._lock.acquire()
        if from_run or self._stopped:
            self._stopped = False
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self._lock.release()

    def _run(self):
        self.start(from_run=True)
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def stop(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        self._stopped = True
        self._timer.cancel()
        self._lock.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here arises from the fact that your code is running top to bottom. Let's look at the order of execution of your statements.

1. You create the countdown object.
2. You run the count.run method.
3. You sleep for 3 seconds.
4. You pause using the count.pause method

In step 2, the count.run method will run to completion before it executes the next line. Meaning the counter will go from 10 all the way to 0 before it runs the next line `time.sleep(3)` and `count.pause()`.

The best way to go about this is to start a new thread that will run in the background so that your other code can execute while your countdown timer continues to count down.

To do this, just import threading at the top  of your file

`import threading`

then when you want to run your counter, instead of doing

`count.run('John Doe', '30')`

create a new thread and start it

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=count.run, args=('John Doe', '30',))
thread.start()

time.sleep(3)
count.pause()
```

I'd recommend researching how to use threads in Python, they're useful.

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/